# Appending non-DataFrame to pandas csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to find out if there is an easier way to append a Date column and an additional info column to my existing csv file. I'm adding these columns because this information is not in the JSON string from the REST API call.

```
import requests
import json
import http.client
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = api.getinfo()
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
if r.status_code != http.client.OK:
    raise requests.HTTPError(r)

jsonstring = json.dumps(r.json()["data"])
load = json.loads(jsonstring)
df = json_normalize(load)
col = ["poolId", "totalPoolCapacity", "totalLocatedCapacity",
       "availableVolumeCapacity", "usedCapacityRate"]
with open('hss.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False, columns=col)

a = pd.read_csv('hss.csv')
a['date'] = [datetime.date.today()] * len(a)
a.to_csv('hss.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('hss.csv')
b['storage system'] = "ssystem22"
b.to_csv('hss.csv')
```

I end up getting extra columns `Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1` in my csv file each time the script is run. Also each time I append it overwrites the old dates.

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,poolId,totalPoolCapacity, totalLocatedCapacity,availableVolumeCapacity,usedCapacityRate,date,storage system
0,155472,223618,565064,51,,2017-04-12,ssystem22
1,943174,819098,262042,58,,2017-04-12,ssystem22
0,764600,966017,046668,71,,2017-04-12,ssystem22
1,764600,335680,487650,76,,2017-04-12,ssystem22
2,373700,459800,304446,67,,2017-04-12,ssystem22
```

Comment: It might be the index, while writing to csv use index=False. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Thank you @Shijo. After adding `index=False` I now only have one instance of `Unnamed: 0` in the csv file.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep reading the file and writing it back again... Why not adding the columns to df before the first write to csv... just curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept researching and found how to fix this. I should have been using the `pd.Series` function. Below is the corrected code:

```
import requests
import json
import http.client
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = api.getinfo()
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
if r.status_code != http.client.OK:
    raise requests.HTTPError(r)

jsonstring = json.dumps(r.json()["data"])
load = json.loads(jsonstring)
df = json_normalize(load)
df['storage system'] = pd.Series('ssystem22', index=df.index)
df['date'] = pd.Series(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),
                       index=df.index)
col = ["poolId", "totalPoolCapacity", "totalLocatedCapacity",
       "availableVolumeCapacity", "usedCapacityRate", "storage system",
       "date"]
with open(csvfile, 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=False, columns=col)
```